# Javascript - convert array to object based on specific data from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
0: {todo: "go for a walk", todoData: "Thu Jan 14 2021", todoId: "kjr4ianh"}
1: {todo: "asdqwe", todoData: "Sun Jan 10 2021", todoId: "kjrg2wwv"}
2: {todo: "asdqwe", todoData: "Sun Jan 10 2021", todoId: "kjrg2xxb"}
```

I would like to convert this array to object based on `todoData`. I want it to something like this:

```
{
 Sun-Jan-10-2021: { 
  todo: {todo: "asdqwe", todoId: "kjrg2wwv"}
  todo: {todo: "asdqwe", todoId: "kjrg2xxb"}
 }
 Thu-Jan-14-2021: {
  todo: {todo: "go for a walk", todoId: "kjr4ianh"}
 }
}
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: please accept an answer as the solution if it solves the problem to close the question

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is not valid `json`, you can group items of the same date in an array as follows:

```js
const data = [
  {todo: "go for a walk", todoData: "Thu Jan 14 2021", todoId: "kjr4ianh"},
  {todo: "asdqwe", todoData: "Sun Jan 10 2021", todoId: "kjrg2wwv"},
  {todo: "asdqwe", todoData: "Sun Jan 10 2021", todoId: "kjrg2xxb"}
];

const res = data.reduce((acc,item) => {
  const { todoData, ...itemData } = item;
  const prev = acc[todoData];
  acc[todoData] = prev
    ? [...prev, itemData]
    : [itemData];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot have same valued multiple keys in an object thus grouping by date.

```
const data = [
  {todo: "go for a walk", todoData: "Thu Jan 14 2021", todoId: "kjr4ianh"},
  {todo: "asdqwe", todoData: "Sun Jan 10 2021", todoId: "kjrg2wwv"},
  {todo: "asdqwe", todoData: "Sun Jan 10 2021", todoId: "kjrg2xxb"}
];

const transformed = {};
data.forEach(elem => {
    if(!transformed[elem.todoData]) {
        transformed[elem.todoData] = []
     }
    transformed[elem.todoData].push({
        todoId: elem.todoId,
        todo: elem.todo
    })
});
```